# jquery change div css on scroll and also change back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a top sticky menu bar. I add some css changes to it when the page starts to scroll past 1px. It works great right now, but I need it to change back when the scroll position is 0. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Here is the js:

```
   $(document).scroll(function(){
if($(this).scrollTop() > 1)
{   
    $('.row-1').css({"box-shadow":"0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)"});
 $('.row-1').css({"opacity":"0.9"});
}
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS:

```
.row-1 { /* some styles for row 1 */ }
.row-1.scrolled { 
   box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rbga(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Then simply toggle that scrolling class:

```
 $(document).scroll(function(){
     $('.row-1').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var row = $('.row-1'), scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > 1)
    {   
        row .css({"box-shadow":"0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)"});
        row .css({"opacity":"0.9"});
    }
    else if (scrollTop <= 1)
    {
        row.css({"box-shadow":"none"});
        row.css({"opacity":"1"});
    }
});
```

But you should use a css class and just toggle it. Like in the David Hedlund response.

Comment: +1 or you can define a css class, and then remove it or add it as needed.